# HD video streaming in gingerbread and ICS

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

i am really not getting anything on net related to this topic. I wanted to do HD video streaming on gingerbread and on ICS. I tried to play various HD video(mp4) locally on blaze ported with gingerbread, but not able to play. First of all i am not getting why it's not able to play video locally.

And the second thing i kept videos on server, but on pandaboard, i am able to hear sound only no picture.

I am wondering no body ever tried to do streaming of HD video. And do we always need to compress those videos to do streaming.

I am really helpless and i searched alot, but there is no solution for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

part to check
Video Encoding Recommendations

Table 2. Examples of supported video encoding parameters.
    SD (Low quality)    SD (High quality)   **HD (Not available on all devices)**

I guess the device your using is not supporting HD

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was able to play HD video on ICS, using blaze. It seems that the problem was wowza server, which was not able to stream the HD video. We upgraded and not it's working. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Hi manisha since your working with wowza I have a question for you are you able to play the video in HTC with ICS?

Comment: Can you tell me encoding format they used to make it compatible will all the version of android? I am encoding it with H.264 recommended by  android but facing issues with samsung and HTC

Comment: i didn't try it with HTC, we have tried it on Blaze with ICS ported on it. The encoding format was h.264 of the clip which i was using. And ICS by default has HD video streaming support.